# ASP.NET 5.0 find controllers on another assembly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

My company will develop several services using ASP.NET 5. These services will provide both REST and gRPC APIs. Different teams will be developing them.

To increase developer productivity and to have a consistent HTTP pipeline we want to provide a NuGet package that will configure this HTTP pipeline (only the middlewares we want and in the correct order), configure logging (Serilog) and configuration (Azure App Configuration), and provide other helpers as well.

In order to do that I have created a library where we create the ASP.NET host with a standard startup class. Then I have created a sample ASP.NET 5 consuming this library via NuGet and started the application. The HTTP pipeline works correctly, but the controllers I have defined in the service assembly (not the library) are not found.

Does anyone know whats is the logic ASP.NET 5 uses to find the controllers? I did some research and tried some fixes, but none of them solved my issue.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

We could share controllers, views, Razor Pages and more with Application Parts.

*Application Parts allow ASP.NET Core to discover controllers, view components, tag helpers, Razor Pages, razor compilation sources, and more. AssemblyPart is an Application part. AssemblyPart encapsulates an assembly reference and exposes types and compilation references.*

You could refer the following steps to use Application Parts.

1. Create a ClassLibray (.net core) named "MySharedApp", and add the following package via NuGet.

   - Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded
   - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
2. Add the Controller and Views with the following folder structure:

   [image]

   MySharedController.cs:

   ```
    //Require using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    public class MySharedController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return Ok("Message from shared assembly!");
        }

        public IActionResult IndexView()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
   ```

   Index.cshtml:

   ```
    <h1>
        Message from shared assembly!
    </h1>

    <h2> Using a View</h2>
   ```

   [**Note**] For the view pages, right click it and open the **Properties** panel, set the Build Action as "Embedded resource" (it can prevent the view page not found issue in the Main web app).
3. Build the ClassLibrary.
4. In the same solution, create a new Asp.net Core Web Application (MVC application).
5. Right click the **Dependencies**, select "**Add Project Reference...**", select the **MySharedApp** ClassLibary, then click **OK** to add the reference.

   You could also click the **Dependencies**, select "**Add Project Reference...**", then, in the **Browser** tab, Click the "**Browser**" button and select the **MySharedApp.dll**, then click **OK** to add the reference.

   After that, the Dependencies looks as below:

   [image]
6. In the MVC application Startup.ConfigureServices method, use the following code to discover and load the controller and view.

   ```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    { 
        // services.AddControllersWithViews();

        #region
        // Requires MySharedApp.Controllers;
        // Requires using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation;
        // Requires using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
        var assembly = typeof(MySharedController).Assembly;
        services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddApplicationPart(assembly)
            .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

        services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options =>
        { options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(assembly)); });

        #endregion 
    }
   ```
7. After that, add the hyperlink to navigate the controller and view:

   ```
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="MyShared" asp-action="Index">MyShared</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="MyShared" asp-action="IndexView">MyShared View</a>
    </li>
   ```

The test screenshot as below:

[image]

More detail information about using Application Parts, check [Share controllers, views, Razor Pages and more with Application Parts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, but in my case I want the Startup class to be inside my library so I can configure a standard HTTP.

Comment: Use a middleware and control all the flow to your routing as Identity4 does https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/3ff3b46698f48f164ab1b54d124125d63439f9d0/src/IdentityServer4/src/Hosting/IdentityServerMiddleware.cs#L69

Comment: weird that with asp net core 6 this is even working without using  .AddApplicationPart(assembly), i am able to access controller from my API that uses shared controller from another assembly

Comment: "weird that with asp net core 6 this is even working without using .AddApplicationPart(assembly)" ... strange that I can't get it to work either with or without using AddApplicationPart